# RRE and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I found the RRE form

```
1 2 0 -5 7
0 0 1 2 -2
0 0 0 0 0
```

Now I don't know what I should do to find P?

Cheers.

Comment: I worked it out in the end! (I don't know how to delete the post)

Answer (score 2):

To find P, you can perform the same elementary row operations on I that you performed on A:

If you perform the operations $-R_1+R_2, -3R_1+R_3, -2R_2+R_3, -2R_2+R_1$ starting with  I,

this should give the matrix P.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,E$ be $m\times{n}$ matrices.  Matrix $A$ is row-equivalent to $E$ if there exists a finite number of elementary matrices $Q_1,Q_2,...,Q_k$ such that
$$A=Q_kQ_{k-1}...Q_2Q_1E$$
These elementary matrices are obtained from the identity matrix $I$ by a single elementary row operation, if you are not familiar.

Since they are obtained using the Identity Matrix, they are square matrices.

There is also a theorem that states that a square matrix is invertibe iff it can be written as the product of elementary matrices.

So, let $S=Q_kQ_{k-1}...Q_2Q_1$.  Thus, $A=SE\Rightarrow S^{-1}A=E$.  Finally, let $P=S^{-1}$.  Thus, we can see that the $P$ that satisfies our question is the inverse of the matrix obtained by multiplying elementary matrices.